# How does the client (iOS device) know any changes from server?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am developing an iOS app and I am looking for a way that my app is able to know whether the data on the server has changed.

Some approaches come up in my mind:

1) Send a request to the server every 3 seconds. However, with this approach, I am afraid the server is overloaded when the number of devices increases. On the other hand, the performance of my iOS app will be affected.

2) Using iOS push notifications (apns). However, with this approach, my app only receives data from server when it is sleeping or inactive.

Could you please tell me any other approaches or give me any advice. Thanks.

Note: I am using Objective-C, Xcode 7.1.

Comment: push notification is the way to go, i dont know why you think this will only happen when your device is sleeping though...

Comment: Yes Go for Push notification way.

Comment: Oh, I will check on it carefully if the push notification can solve the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> using ios push notification (apns). However, with this approach, my app only receives data from server when it is sleeping or inactive.

This is **NOT** true!

Your App will receive Push Notifications even if the App is active. It would show only an alertView (if implemented) in this case but nothing on the Notifications Bar UI.

You could then implement your logic in **AppDelegate** inside this callback:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
    //Make a Differential Call to the server.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use web sockets for realtime two way connection. Square has a library called [SocketRocket](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket) for this purpose.

Comment: Please mark as the correct answer if you think it is.

Comment: Sorry, I go for Push Notification.

Answer (score 0):

APNS is the correct way to achieve what you want.